# Swift Tableview Refresh Error

Tags: swift, uitableview

I get this error:

[image: image 1]

This is my code:
[image: image 2]

I am using refresh in the tableView section of the project. What could be causing this error during the refresh?

> But in which phase it falls to the fault I could not solve that part

```
var kategoriId = ""
    var refresher = UIRefreshControl()

    var arrayKonularData = [konularData]()
    let singleton = konularClass.sharedGlobal

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Yükleniyor")
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(KonuDetayViewController.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        self.tableview.addSubview(refresher)


        KonulariGetir(sirala: "order by tarih desc")
        navigationController?.delegate = self
        tableview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
    func refresh()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
            {
                self.arrayKonularData.removeAll()
                self.KonulariGetir(sirala: "order by tarih desc")
            }
            if self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
            {
                self.arrayKonularData.removeAll()
                self.KonulariGetir(sirala: "order by indirimpuani desc")
            }

        }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        }

    }
```

> I am taking data from web service in this section

```
func KonulariGetir(sirala:String)
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"http://212.xxx.xxx.xxx:7001/IndirimiKovala/KonuGetir")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "filtre="+sirala
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error")
            }

            if let urlContent = data
            {

                do
                {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let gelenDizi = jsonResult as? NSArray
                    {
                        for i in 0..<gelenDizi.count
                        {

                            if let baslik = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["baslik"] as? String
                            {
                                self.singleton.baslik = baslik
                            }

                            if let indirimPuani = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["indirimpuani"] as? Int
                            {
                                self.singleton.indirimPuani = String(indirimPuani)
                            }
                            if let konuId = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["id"] as? Int
                            {
                                self.singleton.konuId = String(konuId)
                            }
                            if let haberVeren = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["uye"] as? String
                            {
                                self.singleton.haberVerenUye = haberVeren
                            }
                            if let gelenTarih = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["tarih"] as? String
                            {
                                self.singleton.tarih = gelenTarih
                            }
                            if let gelenAktif = (gelenDizi[i] as? NSDictionary)?["aktif"] as? Int
                            {
                                self.singleton.aktif = gelenAktif
                            }


                            self.arrayKonularData.append(konularData.init(baslik: self.singleton.baslik, indirimPuani: self.singleton.indirimPuani, konuId: self.singleton.konuId,haberVeren:self.singleton.haberVerenUye , tarih:self.singleton.tarih,aktif:self.singleton.aktif))


                        }

                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                    }


                }
                catch
                {
                    print("server hatası")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Please add code to the question and not pictures of code.

Comment: As the error in the console says "Index out of range".
.
.
Also: you don't add a `UIRefreshControl` as a subview. There is a `refreshControl` property on `UITableView` that you use. http://cleanswifter.com/uirefreshcontrol-in-ios10/ . (don't know if that's part of the issue, but still worth fixing)

Comment: The console says it's an *out of range* error

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem comes from the part of code where you try to populate tableview. So the possible solution can be in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) delegate methode check if arrayKonularData array is not empty like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: orderCell, for: indexPath)


        if !arrayKonularData.isEmpty {
            .....// Your code
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Another solution (which I thing will be the right solution in your case) add completion function of

```
func KonulariGetir(sirala:String)
```

and reload tableview in the completion method

Comment: If `arrayKonularData` is empty `numberOfRows` returns 0 and `cellForRow` is not called at all.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So the problem does not comes from that part. From the part of code which is provided in question it is hard to find what can be the reason of this error